# Calculate limit os sequence.

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $p_i >0 ~(i=1,2,\ldots)$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty}{\frac{p_n}{p_1+p_2+...+p_n}}=0$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty}{a_n}=a$ prove that $$\lim_{n \to \infty}{\frac{p_1a_n+p_2a_{n-1}+...+p_n a_1}{p_1+p_2+...+p_n}}=a.$$

Now proof attempt:
 $|a_n|$ is bounded as it converges. So: 
$$\left|\frac{p_1a_n+p_2a_{n-1}+...+p_n a_1}{p_1+p_2+...+p_n}-a\right|=\left|\frac{p_1(a_n-a)+p_2(a_{n-1}-a)+...+p_n (a_1-a)}{p_1+p_2+...+p_n}\right| \leq \\
 \leq \frac{|p_1(a_n-a)|+|p_2(a_{n-1}-a)|+...+|p_n (a_1-a)|}{p_1+p_2+...+p_n},$$
and for some $N$ and $M$ we have: 
$$\frac{|p_1(a_n-a)|+|p_2(a_{n-1}-a)|+...+|p_{n-N} (a_{N+1}-a)|+p_{n-N+1}M+...+p_nM}{p_1+p_2+...+p_n}.$$ 
So now what do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have started well and your relation holds true for a fixed natural $N$ and any $n \geq N$. Since $N$ is fixed the part with $\frac{(p_{n-N+1}+...+p_n)M}{p_1+...+p_n}$ will go to zero by your hypothesis(it is a sum of finitely many terms which each go to zero).

For the second term in your fraction, note that $(a_{N+1}-a),...,(a_n-a)$ are all bounded by some $\epsilon$ and that $\frac{p_1+...+p_{n-N}}{p_1+...+p_n}$ tends to one so the whole fraction $\frac{|p_1(a_n-a)+...+p_{n-N}(a_{N+1}-a)|}{p1+...+p_n}$ is bounded above by $\epsilon\frac{p_1+...+p_{n-N}}{p1+...+p_n}$ and goes to zero, whence your proof.

Comment: why does $\frac{p_1+...+p_{n-N}}{p_1+...+p_n}$ tends to 1?

Comment: it equals $1-\frac{p_{n-N+1}+...+p_n}{p_1+...+p_n}$ = $1 - (\frac{p_{n-N+1}}{p_1+...+p_n}+...+\frac{p_{n}}{p_1+...+p_n})$ = 1 - a finite number of terms all going to 0 by your hypothesis.

Comment: I would suggest that you add that for each $m$, $\frac{p_{n-m}}{\sum_{k=1}^n p_k}\to 0$ since $$\left|\frac{p_{n-m}}{\sum_{k=1}^n p_k} \right|\le \frac{p_{n-m}}{\sum_{k=1}^{n-m} p_k}\to 0$$as a consequence of $p_k>0$.